# ActionBar with No TitleBar

Tags: android, android-layout, actionbarsherlock

How to have a fullscreen application ( no title bar ) nad have actionbar for all devices?
When i use

```
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
             WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

actionbar removed.and if i change it to

```
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR | Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
             WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

i have a fullscreen application with action bar **BUT** output is look like

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ptlfw.png]

and myLayout.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="20dip">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

By the way,i'm going to use Sherlock , and wanna ActionItems ( first item in sherlock's samples ) , but with no titlebar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put it on style.xml:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionbar">
    <item name="android:windowFullScreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

And use it in manifest like this:

```
<activity android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@style/MyTheme"></activity>
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to change your parent style within [abs_themes.xml](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/library/res/values/abs__themes.xml)

Go to@

> Library>res>values>abs_themes.xml

open that file and replace a sort of code to@

```
<style name="Sherlock.__Theme" parent="android:Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
```

instead

```
<style name="Sherlock.__Theme" parent="android:Theme.NoTitleBar">
```

**Updated**

Attaching output screen

[image]

Comment: Can i request you give me a small sample?please

Comment: I edited in sample code.,check it again, or uninstall and then install it.

Comment: @Dr.jacky, I mean, I edited within download code in my system. check I added screen shot.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19809/discussion-between-robinhood-and-dr-jacky)

Comment: Maybe library not build correctly or even not build.how to build it?i checked build automatically in Project menu.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by all devices? `ActionBar` is introduced from Honeycomb, and it replaces the  `TitleBar`. You can't have `ActionBar` in pre-Honeycomb devices. In case if you are just targeting Honeycomb and later devices, `Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE` actually removes the `ActionBar`, so please don't use `Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE` for your `ActionBar` to be visible.

Comment: With some library,we can have actionbar in pre-Honycomb.about no title bar feature,please don't remove question!i want do it(like referenced image).tnx

Comment: what you can do is, you can use `<application
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">` only for pre-honeycomb devices, then it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe replacing the window feature settings `Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE` by `Window.FEATURE_ACTION_MODE_OVERLAY` setting will do the trick.